# Spellcheck a string using a sorted dictionary in C

Tags: c, string, file-io, dictionary

I'm trying to check a single word string passed to a function against a sorted dictionary file, and I can't figure out why it isn't working.

The spellchecker is case insensitive, so the original word to check is copied and set to upper case.

Dictionary is in the format of:

word\n
words\n

alphabetical order with newline character after each word, no spaces or any other non letter characters.
The dictionary is being read in with fgets one word at a time.

I have a while loop with fgets, and inside it is a for loop with i < strlen(word) 
The for loop compares one character at a time *(word + i) == *(line + i) else break;

if i == strlen(word) - 1 and it  *(word + i) == *(line + i) it should return 1.
strcmp is also not returning 0 for me.
Any idea why this isn't working?

Note: I'd post a code sample, but it's against school policy.

Comment: the only way to talk about code is to provide the code to the reader!

Comment: there is a space before "words" in your example!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in the format you've given (word1\nword2\nword3\n...) that being sorted doesn't really help you... yet. I think you're expected to build an in-memory array of words (just turn each `\n` into `\0` and set each pointer in the array to the beginning of the word). Then your sort becomes useful and you can do a binary search to find your candidate (and a failure to find it means the candidate is misspelled).

With your ability to binary sort in place, a simple `strcasecmp(word, dictionary[searchpoint]);` will do the case insensitive comparison for you.

As to why your current code isn't working, it would seem your school policy is intended to prevent you from getting direct help on stack overflow... because without seeing your code, a direct answer isn't really possible.

Comment: Actually it's because the school owns the IP rights to the code to prevent legal issues with team projects.

Dictionary has around 200k entries, so I don't think we're supposed to make an array.

Comment: If you're reading your dictionary into memory, as would be implied from your description, going from there to an array probably doesn't add that much overhead; 1.6MB extra on a 64 bit system, 800K on a 32 bit system. Without an array to enable binary searching... are you planning to search linearly? Some other way to get to near the right place? Otherwise it would take forever to check "Zomgthisistakingforever".

Comment: strange! let us talk about "xxx", but you are not supposed to read "xxx". Welcome back to the middle ages